# AWS EC2 Instance appears to be running wrong python version from User Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running a python script on EC2, which works fine when I connect through terminal and run 'python /home/ec2-user/lambda_function.py'. However, when I try to run it through User Data so the script is excuted on start up:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
echo "alias python='/usr/bin/python3.7'" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
python /home/ec2-user/lambda_function.py

--//
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/lambda_function.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
Sep 16 15:54:17 cloud-init[3326]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/lambda_function.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
Sep 16 15:54:17 cloud-init[3326]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/userdata.txt [1]
Sep 16 15:54:17 cloud-init[3326]: cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Sep 16 15:54:17 cloud-init[3326]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
```

It appears as though it is trying to run using python 2, as pandas is definitely installed when I use the python terminal

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul 30 2019, 19:56:38)
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> exit()
[ ~]$ python2
Python 2.7.16 (default, Jul 19 2019, 23:05:17)
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As configured in AWS Linux, cloud-init runs the user-data script in the root user account, so when you explicitly modify `/home/ec2-user/.bashrc`, then source `~/.bashrc` you're talking about two different `.bashrc` files.

I'd suggest explicitly sourcing the `.bashrc` file in the `ec2-user` folder.  Or, you can add something like this to the top of your script to switch the context to the `ec2-user` user if it's been run as root:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $UID -eq 0 ]; then
  sudo chmod 777 "$0"
  exec su ec2-user "$0"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the alias command is not working. As described in [this link](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-make-alias-command-work-in-bash-script-or-bashrc-file/#:%7E:text=%27set%20alias%27%20for%20any%20command,t%20work%20inside%20the%20script.&text=Aliases%20are%20not%20expanded%20when,option%20is%20set%20using%20shopt.) you may need to insert `shopt -s expand_aliases` before the alias command so the bash script is able run correctly.